# error in C "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkbCI.png)

I'm beginning C. I tried to print "helloworld" but it has error

I used visual studio code(Mac). installed C/C++,Code runner

I just follow the C lecture, but occurred error.

anyone know solution this error?

error message = ld: Undefined symbols:
_main, referenced from: 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: In addition to including your code _as text_ in the question, also include the full error message (also as text).